# Count number of occurrences for each item in a list

Tags: python

I want to count how many times each item is displaying in a list. Here is what I have:

```
for i in range(len(alist)):
    print(alist[i], alist.count(i))
```

The issue with this right now is that if the list has for example 7 of the same occurrences, it is printing

```
a 0
a 0
a 0 
a 0
a 0
a 0
a 0
```

rather than what I want which is

```
a 7
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `collections.Counter` for that:

```py
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
print(cnt)  # Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1})
```

Because a `Counter` is a `dict` underneath, you can then do:

```py
for char, count in cnt.items(): 
    print(char, count)

# a 3
# b 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the value of i as an integer, so you need to count the list entry of i, not i itself.

```
print(alist[i], alist.count(alist[i]))
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest:

```
your_list = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A']
for item in set(list):
    print(f'{item} occurs {your_list.count(item)} number of times.')
```

This makes your code more readable :) `set(list)` will return a set, i.e. all unique values within the list. Or you can use `numpy.unique()` to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

## Use collections.defaultdict(int)

When you do this:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(int)
```

Every element that's being added to that dictionary will have default value of 0 e.g

```
my_list=["a","a","b","a","b"]
my_dict = defaultdict(int)

for e in my_list:
   my_dict[e]
print(my_dict)
```

**Output:** {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

### If you want to count amount of each element just increase counter by one when iterating through list

```
my_list=["a","a","b","a","b"]
my_dict = defaultdict(int)

for e in my_list:
    my_dict[e]+=1
```

**Output:** {'a': 3, 'b': 2}

Great explanation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sah0p4ILGRE&t=33s